# Why A Balanced Binary Search Tree's Subtrees Cant Differ More than 1 In Height

Tags: binary-tree

Can anyone mathematically prove me why the following BST definition is always true by using the fact that the height of a BST is always logN where N is the number of nodes.

```
"a binary tree in which the left and right subtrees of every node differ in height by no more than 1."
```

Comment: Because that's the definition of a "balanced" tree.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp updated the question, check it out pls :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree#Overview